# Django multiple annotation for one Case-When

Tags: django

I'm currently trying to annotate multiple value with the same `When` in a `Case` for a Django QuerySet.

Currently I have something like this:

```
            my_qs.annotate(
                dynamic_status_deadfish=Case(
                    when_inactive,
                    when_only_recently_published,
                    when_no_published_ad,
                    when_not_enough_booking,
                    when_low_booking_cnt,
                    default=default,
                    output_field=HStoreField(),
                )
            )
```

with one of those `when` looking like this:

```
        when_inactive = When(
            is_active=False,
            then={"status": stats_cts.INACTIVE, "reason": None},
        )
        when_only_recently_published = When(
            Q(is_old_published_ad_exists=False)
            & Q(is_recently_published_ads_exists=True),
            then={
                "status": stats_cts.PENDING,
                "reason": OwnerStatsStatusReason.RECENTLY_SUSPENDED,
            },
        )
        when_no_published_ad = When(
            Q(is_old_published_ad_exists=False)
            & Q(is_recently_published_ads_exists=False),
            then={
                "status": stats_cts.PENDING,
                "reason": OwnerStatsStatusReason.NO_BOOKABLE_TO_MODERATE,
            },
        )
```

As you can see my output is a dict, or more exactly an Hstore.
Ideally, I'd like one distinct annotation for `status` and for `reason` so that I don't have to deal with serialization and have an easier access to the annotation than with this HSTore

One way would be to duplicate the `when` for `status` and `reason` as the condition are the same, but I don't like it.
Something like this:

```
        when_only_recently_published = When(
            Q(is_old_published_ad_exists=False)
            & Q(is_recently_published_ads_exists=True),
            then=Value(stats_cts.PENDING),
        )

        when_only_recently_published_reason = When(
            Q(is_old_published_ad_exists=False)
            & Q(is_recently_published_ads_exists=True),
            then=Value(OwnerStatsStatusReason.RECENTLY_SUSPENDED),
        )

...

            my_qs.annotate(
                dynamic_status_deadfish=Case(
                    when_inactive,
                    when_only_recently_published,
                    when_no_published_ad,
                    when_not_enough_booking,
                    when_low_booking_cnt,
                    default=default,
                ),
                dynamic_status_deadfish_reason=Case(
                    when_inactive_reason,
                    when_only_recently_published_reason,
                    when_no_published_ad_reason,
                    when_not_enough_booking_reason,
                    when_low_booking_cnt_reason,
                    default=default_reason,
                )
            )
```

Any way to somehow set two annotations in a Case or something similar ?